# Not able to send Email messages in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, email, send

Tried many times but no luck... I don't where the problem. Required help in solving the above code.

```
//SEND MAIL
$mymail=file_get_contents("mailaddress.txt");
$frommail=file_get_contents('CCmail.txt');
$to = $mymail;
$subject = "User details";
$txt = "<b>USER DETAILS</b>\r\n\r\nName: $fname\r\nEmail: $email\r\nContact no: $mobile\r\nProvince: $city $state\r\n Gender: $gender\r\nComment: $comment\r\n\r\n<b>QUESTION & ANSWERS</b>\r\n\r\nGender: $selectedgender\r\nSleeping Hours: $sleep\r\nWorking Hours: $work\r\nWeight & Height: $weightheight\r\nIllness: $illness\r\nAllergies: $allergies\r\nSweating: $sweating\r\nAge: $age\r\nSpecial Care: $care\r\nSleeping Position: $sleepingposition\r\nLevel Of Comfort: $comfort\r\nPreference: $preference\r\n";
$headers = "From: $frommail" . "\r\n" .
"CC: $frommail";
wp_mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
echo"successfull";
}
}
else{
echo"Not Allowed";
}
?>
```

Comment: have you configured your smtp settings for sending emails?

Answer (score 1):

For WordPress (or indeed for any software) to send email messages it needs to have access to a Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) server somewhere on the Internet.

The best way to do this is to

1. install a WordPress plugin like [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/). It takes over from php's rudimentary built-in SMTP handler. It also provides a plugin settings screen where you can configure your email settings.
2. get yourself an account on one of the SMTP services mentioned in the plugin's documentation. I like sendgrid.com for this purpose, because it has a free tier allowing up to 100 messages a day forever.

   You could use the SMTP server belonging to your own email provider. But the big providers like gmail and yahoo really don't like automated email systems sending email through them, and they may refuse connections from your WordPress instance. They especially don't like incorrectly formatted email messages: the kind you might send while debugging your application. They're trying to resist attacks from spammers and cybercreeps.
3. Write and test your code sending only to email accounts under your control (avoiding developer spam to unsuspecting people).

A word to the wise: many countries prohibit "protected health information" -- data about medical patients -- in email messages. It's impossible to guarantee the confidentiality of email due to the way it works.

In the USA it's even illegal for a hospital or doctor to send ANY email to a patient without that patient's consent: the From: and To: fields of the email identify the recipient as a patient of the sender.  Respect your patients' confidentiality!